# How to specify the name of the output executable?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-package-manager

By default the SPM builds the executable target with the same name (uppercase) as the module folder containing its `main.swift`. How do I get it to build the binary with a different file name? I cannot find any instructions on the [SPM manual](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/master/Documentation/Reference.md#name).

Answer (score 6):

With Swift 4, given DemoProject created with `swift package init --type executable`, make the changes to Package.swift (adding the `products` section).

```
// swift-tools-version:4.0
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "DemoProject",
    products: [
        .executable(name: "demo", targets: ["DemoProject"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "DemoProject",
            dependencies: []),
    ]
)
```

This will create an executable called `demo`.

Comment: @taylor-swift I'm curious if this answered your question. You never marked it as such, but never left a comment either.

Answer (score 1):

## Change executable name

In SPM 5.4, You can set `executable` name in `products`.

```swift
.executable(name: "ExecutableName", targets: ["ExecutableTargetName"])
```

## Build the executable product directly

and if you want to build the executable directly, try command `swift build --product ExecutableName`

also you can get where the build result located with `--show-bin-path` parameter

for example `swift build --product ExecutableName --show-bin-path`

## Demo Package.swift

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.4

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "PackageName",
  platforms: [
    .iOS(.v11),
    .macOS(.v10_15),
  ],
  products: [
    .library(name: "LibraryName", targets: ["LibraryTarget"]),
    .executable(name: "ExecutableName", targets: ["ExecutableTargetName"])
  ],
  dependencies: [...],
  targets: [
    .target(
      name: "LibraryTarget",
      dependencies: [...],
      path: "Sources/..."
    ),
    .executableTarget(
      name: "ExecutableTargetName",
      dependencies: [...],
      path: "Sources/..."
    ),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score -2):

I am in favor of using another build system, for example `make`, on top of `swift build`. Currently, `swift build` does not allow defining custom "hooks" to implement various build automation tasks - generating code, copying resources, deploying the executable, etc. Once you use `make` you can define whichever tasks you desire, in particular, renaming the binary.